# What does "learned mythology" mean?

Tags: word-choice

> Academics in the humanities played an active part by **conceiving a real
> mythology** of Sweden’s grand prehistoric past. According to the multi-talented Uppsala professor
> Olaus Rudbeck, Scandinavia, with
> Sweden at its centre, had actually been Atlantis, Plato’s ideal
> society, which made Sweden the origin of the whole of European
> civilisation. Rudbeck generously apportioned this honour equally to
> the western and eastern halves of the kingdom. Likewise, Daniel
> Juslenius, at Åbo Akademi, repeated in his dissertation Aboa vetus et
> nova (Åbo Old and New) in 1700 a story fabricated in the sixteenth
> century that his town had been founded immediately after the Flood by
> Noah’s son Magog Of course, the question is how many people had the
> opportunity to acquaint themselves with these **learned mythologies.**
>
> (bolds by me)
>
> A history of Finland by Henrik Meinander

I have two questions:

1. What does it mean **to conceive a real mythology of Sweden’s past**? Does it mean that the academics fabricated a mythology based on Sweden's actual history?
2. What is a learned mythology? According to Cambridge dictionary, one of the meanings of the word "learned" is: Learned behaviour has been copied from others. Does this refer to the meaning in the first question? That the mythologies are fictive?

Comment: I am going to guess that “real” is a mistranslation for something that was intended to mean “pseudo-historical.”

Comment: Sometimes, the word learned is actually written as: learnéd. As in: learnéd individuals.

Answer (score 1):

(1) *Prehistoric* means *of the time before history was written down.* The academics fabricated a mythology linking prehistoric Sweden to European myths such as that of [Atlantis](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/atlantis).

(2) This is Cambridge's first definition of *learned*, pronounced as two syllables. The mythologies were made up by academics (learned men) and ordinary folk may not have known about them.

Comment: I suppose it could be an ironic use of learned but we would have to read the book to find out.

Answer (score 0):

"Mythology" means a collection of fictional or semi-fictional stories, usually involving heroes and/or the supernatural. and often describing a people's past.

In this case, by a "real mythology", I think the writer means, not a set of stories that are true, but rather, a set of stories that really meet the definition of mythology. That is, he is emphasizing that they are not true, but fictional. They are not a "true history" but a "real mythology". They are "really a mythology".

"Learned" means facts or behavior that one has acquired from someone else or has developed over time. In this case, by "learned mythology" he means that the stories have been invented by one group and then passed on to others.